# I get an error when trying to extract the tor browser .tar.xz file, what did i do wrong?

Tags: command-line, tar, tor

sudo tar -xf [TB archive]

tar: [TB: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Are you literally typing `sudo tar -xf [TB archive]`? You need to replace `[TB archive]` with the actual name of the archive file that you downloaded